# How to retreive data from mysql database and parse it in textview?

Tags: android

im new in programming with android , i am trying to get data from mysql database and parse it into textView , i tried to get json and it works fine. But when i try to parse it into textView it doesn't work ?? 
Please any help to provide ??
Here is my java method :

```
protected String doInBackground(Void...params){
            InputStream is=null;
            String result="";

            try{

                URL url = new URL(json_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                is = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                while((json_string = reader.readLine())!=null){

                    stringBuilder.append(json_string+"\n");
                }
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
                JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("utilisateur");
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    oneObject.getString("nom");//return the address
                    oneObject.getString("prenom");//return the name
                }


                reader.close();
                is.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return stringBuilder.toString().trim();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

This is my php code :

```
<?php

        $DB_USER='mootaz'; 
        $DB_PASS='mootaz'; 
        $DB_HOST='localhost';
        $DB_NAME='mvoting_db_1.0.0.0';


        $sql = "select * from utilisateur where role='administrateur';";

        $con = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        $response = array();

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

            array_push($response,array("name"=>$row[3],"prenom"=>$row[4]));
        }

        echo json_encode(array("utilisateur"=>$response));

        mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you getting data that store in object and then after bind data into text view like below code..

make pojo class for your response like

```
public class User {
private String name,addres;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddres() {
    return addres;
}

public void setAddres(String addres) {
    this.addres = addres;
}
```

}
make array list to store data like below ..

```
 private List<User> mUserList=new ArrayList<>();
```

when you doInBackground method used below like ..

```
    User user=new User();
 for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length();i++){
    JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    user.setAddres(oneObject.getString("nom"));//return the address
    user.setName(oneObject.getString("prenom"));//return the name
    mUserList.add(user);
 }
```

then after onPostExecute bind data.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        super.onPostExecute(o);
        for(User user:mUserList)
        {
            textview.setText(user.getAddres());
        }
    }
```

Comment: private List<User> mUserList=new ArrayList<>(); make list as a local in activity class.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException ; it gets me that error in JSONObject ??

Comment: it means your json format are different and your parsing is wrong.

Comment: pl post your json data.

Comment: post your url when you getting json data.

Comment: i added my php file above , check it out

Comment: only provide your json output data.

Comment: here is my json output data  : {"utilisateur":[{"name":"Abdellatif","prenom":"Mootaz"}]}